# Simultaneous Studies in Mechanical Turk with Worker Exclusions

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am trying to see if there is a way to run 2 or more studies on Amazon Mechanical Turk simultaneously. However, in doing so, workers who participate in one of the studies should not be able to complete another one of my studies. I have heard about doing this using the "Survey Batch" option in TurkPrime, but I am not sure if there is a way to run the same logic through Mechanical Turk.

I completed some research in understanding how to do this process with multiple studies across different periods of time. For cases like these, I know the way to go is to download the worker ID and manually include a custom qualification so that they would not complete the second study that I am running. However, is there a way to exclude workers from completing both studies if the studies were to be conducted simultaneously?

In short, I would expect to run two studies together. If participant A already submitted answers for Study 1, they cannot close the window and immediately start Study 2, which is another study running at the same time when Study 1 was opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that using the MTurk web site directly it is not possible to run 2 studies simultaneously unless you either put the blocking logic within your study or you hook into the mturk api or both.

The only solution I am aware of is using the survey group feature using Turkprime.com